# Android Kotlin: Failed StateFlow initialization on fake Repository between test cases in Unit test

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, testing, kotlin-coroutines

I've written unit tests for my viewmodel, which takes a fake repository as a constructor. When I run my insertNote() test standalone, which insert a value to a StateFlow in my repository and evaluates a list size, it passes as it should be, but when I run the whole test class, it fails, which seems to be due to the fact that my insertMaxNote() test runs before the InsertNote() and somehow the StateFlow remembers the inserted value, however I reinitialized my fakeRepository in the setUp() function, which runs before every test case, so the collected values should be independent in every testcase, if I'm correct. Do You have any idea why the StateFlow's value is stored?

My Test class:

```
class MetronomeViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    //SUT
    private lateinit var metronomeViewModel: MetronomeViewModel
    //FAKES
    private lateinit var fakeMetronomeRepository: FakeMetronomeRepository

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        fakeMetronomeRepository = FakeMetronomeRepository()
        metronomeViewModel = MetronomeViewModel(
            fakeMetronomeRepository
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun startService() = runTest {
        fakeMetronomeRepository.playMetronome()
        val actualIsPlaying = metronomeViewModel.getMetronomeState().first().isPlaying
        assertEquals(true,actualIsPlaying)
    }

    @Test
    fun stopService() = runTest {
        fakeMetronomeRepository.playMetronome()
        fakeMetronomeRepository.pauseMetronome()
        val actualIsPlaying = metronomeViewModel.getMetronomeState().first().isPlaying
        assertEquals(false,actualIsPlaying)
    }

    @Test
    fun getMetronomeState() = runTest {
        val expectedMetronomeState = MetronomeState.initial_state
        val actualMetronomeState = metronomeViewModel.getMetronomeState().first()
        assertEquals(expectedMetronomeState,actualMetronomeState)
    }

    @Test
    fun insertNote() = runTest {
        val previousBeatListSize = metronomeViewModel.getMetronomeState().first().beatList.size
        metronomeViewModel.insertNote()
        val actualBeatListSize = metronomeViewModel.getMetronomeState().first().beatList.size
        assertEquals(previousBeatListSize + 1,actualBeatListSize)
    }

    @Test
    fun removeNote() = runTest {
        val previousBeatListSize = metronomeViewModel.getMetronomeState().first().beatList.size
        metronomeViewModel.removeNote()
        val actualBeatListSize = metronomeViewModel.getMetronomeState().first().beatList.size
        assertEquals(previousBeatListSize - 1,actualBeatListSize)
    }

    @Test
    fun insertMaxNote() = runTest {
        try {
            for (i in 0..FakeMetronomeRepository.MAX_NOTE) {
                metronomeViewModel.insertNote()
            }
        } catch (e : Exception) {
            assertEquals("Only ${FakeMetronomeRepository.MAX_NOTE} notes are allowed!",e.message)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun removeMinNote() = runTest {
        try {
            for (i in FakeMetronomeRepository.MAX_NOTE downTo FakeMetronomeRepository.MIN_NOTE) {
                metronomeViewModel.removeNote()
            }
        } catch (e : Exception) {
            assertEquals("At least ${FakeMetronomeRepository.MIN_NOTE} notes are necessary!",e.message)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun setBPM() = runTest {
        val expectedBPM = 120
        metronomeViewModel.setBPM(expectedBPM)
        val actualBPM = metronomeViewModel.getMetronomeState().first().bpm
        assertEquals(expectedBPM,actualBPM)
        val expectedTempo = 500L
        val actualTempo = metronomeViewModel.getMetronomeState().first().tempo
        assertEquals(expectedTempo,actualTempo)
    }

    @Test
    fun setRhythm() = runTest {
        val previousRhythm = metronomeViewModel.getMetronomeState().first().rhythm
        metronomeViewModel.setRhythm()
        val actualRhythm = metronomeViewModel.getMetronomeState().first().rhythm
        assertEquals(previousRhythm.getNextRhythm(),actualRhythm)
    }

    @Test
    fun setToneByIndex() = runTest {
        metronomeViewModel.setToneByIndex(0)
        val expectedBeat = Beat.LOUDER
        val actualBeat = metronomeViewModel.getMetronomeState().first().beatList.first()
        assertEquals(expectedBeat, actualBeat)
    }
}
```

And my fake repository:

```
class FakeMetronomeRepository : MetronomeRepository {
    companion object {
        const val MIN_NOTE = 3
        const val MAX_NOTE = 8
        private const val MIN_IN_MILLIS = 60000
    }

    private var _metronomeState : MutableStateFlow<MetronomeState> = MutableStateFlow(MetronomeState.initial_state)
    override val metronomeState : StateFlow<MetronomeState> = _metronomeState.asStateFlow()

    override suspend fun playMetronome() {
        _metronomeState.update {
            it.copy(
                isPlaying = true
            )
        }
    }

    override fun pauseMetronome() {
        _metronomeState.update {
            it.copy(
                isPlaying = false
            )
        }
    }

    override fun setRhythm() {
        _metronomeState.update {
            it.copy(
                rhythm = it.rhythm.getNextRhythm()
            )
        }
        setBPM(_metronomeState.value.bpm)
    }

    override fun setBPM(value: Int) {
        _metronomeState.update {
            it.copy(
                bpm = value,
                tempo = (MIN_IN_MILLIS / (value * it.rhythm.value)).toLong()
            )
        }
    }

    override fun insertNote() {
        if (_metronomeState.value.beatList.size < MAX_NOTE) {
            _metronomeState.update {
                it.copy(
                    beatList = it.beatList
                        .apply {
                            add(Beat.LOUD)
                        }
                )
            }
        } else {
            throw Exception("Only $MAX_NOTE notes are allowed!")
        }
    }

    override fun removeNote() {
        if (_metronomeState.value.beatList.size > MIN_NOTE) {
            _metronomeState.update {
                it.copy(
                    beatList = it.beatList
                        .apply {
                            if (it.beatListIterator != this.size - 1) removeLast()
                        }
                )
            }
        } else {
            throw Exception("At least $MIN_NOTE notes are necessary!")
        }
    }

    override fun setToneByIndex(index: Int) {
        _metronomeState.update {
            it.copy(
                beatList = it.beatList.apply {
                    this[index] = it.beatList[index].getNextTone()
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Thank You in advance!

I already tried the Turbine library to collect value from the StateFlow, but the result was the same.